# How to deserialize to base type if type information is missing in json request?

Tags: json, spring, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

We are stuck with a issue where we have a non abstract parent class with 2 sub classes as shown below. When type information is provided the default deserialization process of Jackson works fine. But when no information is provided as the request object is of base class; the deserilization process gets fail.

```
@JsonTypeName("Vehicle")
@JsonTypeInfo(  
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
        property = "type"
)  
@JsonSubTypes({  
        @Type(value = Car.class),
        @Type(value = Bicycle.class) 
})
class Vehicle{
   int number;
}

@JsonTypeName("Car")
class Car extends Vehicle{
int seatingCapacity;
}

@JsonTypeName("Bicycle")
class Bicycle extends Vehicle{
String handleType;
}
```

The following request works fine:

```
{
  "type" : "Car",
   "number": "1244"
   "seatingCapacity": 2
}
```

But the following request fails:

```
{
   "number": "2222"
}
```

Our expectation is that if type information is missing than the last json request should get deserialized to base class i.e. Vehicle.

Could you please help us with this? Thanks !

**Using spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE**

Answer (score 4):

You should update your JsonTypeInfo

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
        property = "type",
        defaultImpl = Vehicle.class
)
```

Also, use the latest version of Jackson dependency
Hope It's work.

Comment: Hello Piyush, On doing what you have suggested we are getting this error:  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class Car is not subtype of Bicycle.

Comment: @Jaraws can you try with replace inside @JsonTypeInfo-> include with this include= JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1538 see here if it helps you

Comment: Hello Piyush, thanks for the provided reference. It certainly helped us.